# how can i make uiview on the Uinavigationbar

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I am doing one iphone app. In this app i want to **disable the back navigationleftbarbutton**. I have used this below code for disable the navigationleftbarbutton but it is not working. Now i have created one view and i have added in uinavigationbar. But now i want to make that view in transparent view. And also how can i remove my customview(myview1) from the navigationbar.  I have attached my code. please some body help me to solve my issue.

**Disable Code:**

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setEnabled:NO];
```

**And This is my customview Code:**

```
myview1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40)];
myview1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:myview1];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = button;
```

How can i make myview is transparent view. And how can i remove mycustomview(myview1) from navigationbar. Thanks in advance.

Comment: SO you want it to be transparent, purely so you can hide the original NavigationBar??

Comment: @JeffKranenburg i want to disable the back button using transparent uiview. how can i do this?

Comment: Why don't you set up a UIViewController with a UINavigationBar - if you don't set up the UINavigationController, you won't get the back button.

Comment: i want visible the back button. But i want that back button do not work any action.

Comment: @JeffKranenburg how can i add the uiview on the uiwindow

Comment: You don't - you add a ViewController to the UIWindow or a UIView to a UINavigationController in your case

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21893/discussion-between-gopinath-and-jeff-kranenburg)

Answer (score 0):

you can hide navigation back button by writing code below:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.hidden = YES;
```

and your view ie myview can be transparent by changing alpha value of the view

```
[myview setAlpha:0.3];   //alpha value ranges from 0 to 1
```

By settign alpha value 0.0 makes view transparent and increases transparency as u increases alpha value

Comment: @sathis i don't want to hide my leftbarbutton. i want to disable

Comment: @Gopinath:  I think you cannot disable left back button because it is handled by navigation controller.

there is another way to handle it:
first hide the back button by using above code. Then create your own custom button and add on leftNavigationItem. after that  you can enable or disable that cuttom button by its reference.